# SUMPRODUCT with Dates for Criteria

Tags: excel

I am trying to obtain an average of an array of fields with the following simple formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Main!BA:BA, Main!CY:CY, --(Main!D:D >=D3, Main!D:D <=E3))
```

I'm getting a #DIV/0! error. I have no clue why it's dividing anything. Please help!

Basically, how can I get the sum product of columns D vs E between the dates 11/05 to 11/27.

[image: List to be summed.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `*` or `+` depending on whether you want `AND` or `OR`.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Main!BA:BA, Main!CY:CY, (Main!D:D >=D3)*(Main!D:D <=E3))
```

One more note:

You want to limit the references to only that with data as this formula will do a lot of unneeded calculations.

Comment: Would the `+` be an appropriate equivalent for an `OR`? I feel like it would dupe the results if a cell covers both criteria (it can't happen in this case, but generally speaking).

Comment: In this case `AND` is the appropriate method, because we want dates that are bot less than one and greater than another.  If using `OR` we would get all the values, because the dates are either less than one OR greater than the other.  @FernandoJ.Rivera

Comment: @FernandoJ.Rivera To avoid double-counting when using + you can use this type of syntax: `((A1:A10="x")+(B1:B10="y")>0)+0`

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT(Main!BA:BA, Main!CY:CY, (Main!D:D >=D3)*(Main!D:D <=E3))` Will also result in a "Divide by zero" error

Comment: @Rookie Only if you have that error in the data.  The formula itself will not throw that error.  You will need to deal with the error in the data.

Comment: I am searching and I cannot find any zero values. In the sheet called "Main" nothing is being divided nor are there any values less than one.

Comment: Also as I stated you need limit the ranges to that with data.  if you are including cells in the full column references that include text or errors it will error.  make sure you are limiting the references.

Comment: As it turns out all the solutions provided within this post are correct. I found a #DIV/0 error in the main sheet that was causing it.

Answer (score 3):

From looking at your worksheet, you want this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(D:D*E:E*(C:C>=$C$27)*(C:C<=$C$49))
```

Comment: Hi @Chris Mack, I would you to note that in the actual work sheet, columns D and E are actually very separate columns, that is, they aren't adjacent. They are essentailly columns BA and CY. Very far apart.

Comment: Thanks, I've amended the formula.